# Avro Dynamic schema change on Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, hortonworks-data-platform, jackson-dataformat-avro

I have some data coming in avro format v1 and getting stored in HDFS under a partition dt=yyyymmdd.
Now the data is maintained with two versions, v1 and v2 under the same partition.
Is it feasible to maintain a single hive table for two different versions?

Answer (score 1):

[Avro defines a schema evolution protocol](http://getindata.com/schema-evolution-with-avro-and-hive/)

If v2 has simply added a field with a default value, for example, then updating the table with that schema, it can read the entirety of the old data, as it'll simply return the default values where they are missing.

If you've broken compatibility, you must make a separate table, then union the two to get a consistent result set

Comment: having a scenario where new fields are added in the new version and at the same time for few of the existing columns sizes/namespace/type are changed. Example as below 

       {
        "type": "fixed",
        "name": "abcd",
        "namespace": "com.abc.bcd",
        "doc": "",
        "size": 1
       }

Comment: You only added one example, so I don't understand the comment. Renaming a field is not backwards compatible until you add an alias to the previous name

Comment: if v1 Schema
 { "type": "fixed", "name": "abcd", "namespace": "com.abc.bcd", "doc": "", "size": 1 }
v2 schema
 { "type": "fixed", "name": "abcd", "namespace": "com.abc.bcd", "doc": "", "size": 16 }
In the above two versions the size is varying. Is there any way translating the schema according to data by having single hive table

Comment: Hive doesn't have a fixed data type. In the hive documentation... *Avro Fixeds are converted to Array[smallint]*. And array columns have no fixed size